# How to replace variable with groupby using values from quantiles in python

Tags: python, group-by, quantile

I have a df as shown below:

```
>>> df.head()
group_type  value
G1          125.23
G1          107.19
G1          117.37
G1          102.68
G2          185.58
G1          82.31
G2          21.82
G2          168.21
G2          134.17
G1          71.45
```

I have calculated the quantile values within each group as below:

```
>>> lowtail = df.groupby('group_type')['value'].quantile(0.25)
>>> lowtail
group_type
G1             103.8075
G2             59.0425
Name: value, dtype: float64


>>> hightail = df.groupby('group_type')['value'].quantile(0.75)
>>> hightail
group_type
G1           123.2650
G2           172.5525
Name: value, dtype: float64
```

Now, I need to replace the `value` in `df` within each `group_type` with the calculated quantile values, `lowtail` and `hightail` based on the conditions if:

1. df.groupby('group_type')['value'] < the value of corresponding group_type in lowtail then replace with lowtail value of the corresponding group_type
2. df.groupby('group_type')['value'] > the value of corresponding group_type in hightail then replace with hightail value of the corresponding group_type

The desired output looks like:

```
group_type  value   new_value
G1          125.23  123.2650
G1          107.19  107.19
G1          117.37  117.37
G1          102.68  103.8075
G2          185.58  172.5525
G1          82.31   103.8075
G2          21.82   59.0425
G2          168.21  168.21    
G2          134.17  134.17
G1          71.45   103.8075
```

I am able to do a simple replace with fixed values

```
df.loc[df[value] < lowtail, [value]] = lowtail
```

but could not condition and replace using the `groupby`. Can anyone help here.

Comment: have you tried update statement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is that what you want to code ? :

```
grp = df.groupby('group_type')['value']
low, high = grp.quantile(0.25), grp.quantile(0.75)    

def f(x):
    if x.value < low[x.name]:
        return low[x.name]
    elif x.value > high[x.name]:
        return high[x.name]
    else:
        return x.value
df['new_value'] = df.apply(f, axis=1)
```

Comment: how could it be used to groupby by two variables and calcuate the median within the two groupby variables. Thereafter, replacing the outliers with the groupby median?